# what is Customer portal in salesforce

Tags: customer-portal

It might be a simple one. But i am new to this topic.

can anybody explain what is customer portal in salesforce?

Why we are using customer portal in salesforce?

How many types of customer portal are we have?

Where we can use customer portal?

Please don't provide any salesforce related sites like the following....

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiqqLbBvvXNAhUDQo8KHQTmCrQQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fhelp%2Fdoc%2Fen%2Fcustomer_portal_setting_up.htm&usg=AFQjCNHbXSoVS05px2ur-3EvzKCj9i8lXw&cad=rja

http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/13/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_customer_portal_implementation_guide.pdf

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=customer+portal+in+salesforce&oq=customer+portal+in+salesforce&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l3.5481j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

I already gone through these sites. But these sites does not gives me more clarity about portals.

Please provide answer what you understand about portals...

provide such a good answer that clearly satisfies me....

thanks in advance

KS Kumaar

Answer (score 2):

First, you can no longer create a new "customer portal" in a Salesforce Org unless your org already has portals enabled. Portals have been deprecated and replaced by "Salesforce Communities" for approximately 3 yrs now. Communities can be created using a variety of license types. The most common licenses are Customer Community, Customer Community Plus and Partner Community.

The main differences between the licenses are the Salesforce CRM objects that Community users will have access too. Community user's access is fully customizable by each Salesforce org that creates their own custom community. All of them allow access to Custom Objects. Each handles sharing a bit differently. A customer community user doesn't have a role, but users with the other two licenses I mentioned do (yes, I know that's confusing).

What are they for? The answer to that can vary greatly as it's up to you to decide what you want to accomplish with one. Generally speaking they're for providing support and information to one's customers and partners. They can also be used for sharing account information and business deals with partners. They can be used to create and resolve support cases, collect ideas, hold discussions on your organization's products, and just about anything else you can think of. In essence, they're just like a secure web site where you can provide customers access to support content and knowledge bases, contests, promotions, or anything else you would choose to do.

Comment: I understood what you are trying to say. But we have an option in salesforce org that is "Enable customer portal" in Build-->Customize-->Customer Portal--->Customer Portal Settings.
once we enable this, we can able to create Customer Portal Setup right?
what is use of this?
Thank you for your response @crmprogdev

Comment: If your org doesn't already have a customer portal, even though you see that option as part of your menu, you won't be able to use it. Portals were used before Communities were developed. They didn't have all of the bells and whistles. They were very spartan and only had what looked like very plain detail pages with limited functionality.